# MongoDB Querying for object property in list

Tags: json, mongodb, querying

Let's say I do have a document like this:

```
{
    _id: "cow",
    comments: [
        {user: "karl", comment: "I like cows.", at: /*a date*/},
        {user: "harry", comment: "Cows are the best.", at: /*a date*/}
    ]
}
```

Now I want to collect all the comments that `"karl"` left in my db. Or just the ones on a certain date. The `"comments"` are indexed, how can I query for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like:

```
db.foo.find({"comments.user":"karl", "comments.at":{$gt:{dateObject}});
```

Haven't tested but you get the idea; you can drill down on items as such.

I'd recommend going through this site as it drives you through a great deal of interactive tutorials: [Interactive Tutorial](http://mongly.com/)

Answer (score 7):

You should use $elemMatch to match more than one conditions in same doc.

Something like:

```
db.foo.find({comments: {"$elemMatch": {user: "karl", at: {$gt:{dateObject}}}})
```

See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/) for more details.

Comment: the mongodb website changed their documentation urls - anyway I updated my answer with something relevant on the new site.